# Fetch value of hyperlink and click on link in python selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, hyperlink

I want to fetch the value of the agents logged in (which is dynamic , see bold text) and click on the link as well, Both link and value are 1 in this case but that is dynamic. I am using selenium webdriver and python

Emergency Phone00s**1**100011100 %100 %0

```html
<tbody role="rowgroup"><tr data-uid="9e893d0e-4dc1-4e13-bdda-f63f038100c6" role="row"><td class="align-left" role="gridcell">Emergency Phone</td><td role="gridcell"><a data-click="queueDetailsCmd" href="#">0</a></td><td role="gridcell">0s</td><td role="gridcell"><a data-click="agentsLoggedOnCmd" href="#">1</a></td><td class="agentsReady" role="gridcell"><a data-click="agentsReadyCmd" href="#">1</a></td><td class="agentsBusy" role="gridcell"><a data-click="agentsBusyCmd" href="#">0</a></td><td class="agentsInPause" role="gridcell"><a data-click="agentsInPauseCmd" href="#">0</a></td><td role="gridcell">0</td><td role="gridcell">1</td><td role="gridcell">1</td><td role="gridcell">100 %</td><td role="gridcell">100 %</td><td role="gridcell">0</td></tr></tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To get text of all td's :**

use :

```
td = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody//tr//td')
for tableData in td:
     cellData = tableData .text
```